# jQuery: "diff" two tables; display rows not in common

Tags: jquery

### In a checkout application:

Need to display only the recently added items.

### Constraints:

No control over submit action in form.
No control over "row adding" mechanism

### My idea:

1. Clone table upon document load
2. Compare or 'diff' table against clone at "finish"
3. Display unique rows

### Where I'm at so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/XLsCx/10/

I can't get unique rows to display in new table. The results are wrong too, if you look at what's highlighted in Red.

**( sounds of crickets chirping )**
Haven't figured it out yet, huh? Well, I did ...finally.

http://jsfiddle.net/FkrBc/

I'll submit this as an answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read 'em and weep ladies!

http://jsfiddle.net/FkrBc/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to clone all table, you just have to store the last `tr` and change the style of all `tr` which comes after the stored on button click.

Try this:

```
var $lastRow;
function updateLastRow() {
    $lastRow = $('#firstTable tr:last')
}

updateLastRow();

$("#houston button").click ( function () {
    var row = "<tr><td>new</td><td>item</td><td>added</td></tr>";
    $(row).insertAfter('#firstTable tbody>tr:last');
});

$("#newItems button").click ( function () {
    $lastRow.nextAll().find('td:eq(1)').css('background-color', 'red');
    updateLastRow();
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XLsCx/11/)

Comment: The table is sorted alphabetically in production -- so I can't count on the new row being last. Just made up a quick row add mechanism to test with. See new fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/XLsCx/14/